How to get all Pagerduty incident notes via Pdpyras library
I know how to make a GET request to the incident notes API end but how do I leverage the pdpyras library to do so? I can get all incidents
from pdpyras import APISession
api_token = 'MY_TOKEN'
session = APISession(api_token)

for incident in session.iter_all('incidents'):
    print(incident)

but i cannot see any information related to notes, so i am suspecting i should not be passing 'incidents' to my sessions.iter_all method. I have been looking through their source code but I have not gotten anywhere with that. Any help would be appreciated.

Incident notes are retrieved from a separate endpoint (https://api.pagerduty.com /incidents/{id}/notes), where {id} is the incident ID.
It depends a bit on how much data is in your account, but the simplest way would be to fetch all of your incidents, then iterate through the incident IDs to fetch the incident notes.

i see.. i was hoping i can leverage the pdpyras library but this also works for me i guess
